# How to get spplot (lattice) to not draw borders around polygons

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, lattice

I have a tally by zip code which is a lot of polygons to plot (30,357 to be precise).  Consequently when I `pdf` the `spplot` all I see are the borders not the choropleth interiors.

Therefore, I'd like to turn off plotting the borders, or at least be able to make them much, much thinner.  However, digging around in `?spplot` and its various offshoots (the panel function, levelplot, etc.) have come up empty.

Here's an example to work with (the borders aren't that prominent here but they would be given a bajillion polygons):

```
library(sp)
Srs1 = Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(2,4,4,1,2),c(2,3,5,4,2)))), "s1")
Srs2 = Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(5,4,2,5),c(2,3,2,2)))), "s2")

SpDF <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame( SpatialPolygons(list(Srs1,Srs2)), 
            data.frame( z=1:2, row.names=c("s1","s2") ) )
spplot(SpDF, zcol="z")
```

[image: spplot]

Comment: I've incorporated this answer and a few other examples of choropleth coloring into [this gis.SE question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/36877/how-do-i-change-the-polygon-fill-color-and-border-color-for-spatialpolygons-obje/36878#36878).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you just need to set `col="transparent"`, like so:

```
spplot(SpDF, zcol="z", col="transparent")
```

[image]

Comment: `col=NA` will save your fingers 11 keystrokes :) Also, don't use the default colour palette or you'll have white polygons on a white background...

Comment: I'd assumed `col` was the color of the interior, but of course it makes total sense it'd be the borders.  Thanks!