# Overplotting two SpatialPolygonsDataFrames with spplot

Tags: r, spatial

I have a bunch of data which I've plotted at the county level, [without borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682212/how-to-get-spplot-lattice-to-not-draw-borders-around-polygons).  I'd like to add in state boundaries.  I have a state shapefile (polygons), but `spplot` doesn't seem to have any way to add on top of the previous map.  Is there any way to do this without rewriting the panel function to take two SPDFs (which seems pretty specialized for what is likely a problem other people have)?

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(sp)
Srs1 = Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(2,4,4,1,2),c(2,3,5,4,2)))), "s1")
Srs2 = Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(5,4,2,5),c(2,3,2,2)))), "s2")

county <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame( SpatialPolygons(list(Srs1,Srs2)), 
                                  data.frame( z=1:2, row.names=c("s1","s2") ) )

SrsA <- Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(3,5,5,1,3),c(3,4,6,5,3)))),"sA")
state <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame( SpatialPolygons(list(SrsA)),
                                  data.frame( z=1,row.names="sA" ))

spplot( county, zcol="z",col=NA )
spplot( state, add=TRUE ) # Note the add=TRUE does nothing here, but that's the spirit of what I want to accomplish
```

Comment: I'd just use base graphics : plot(foo, col=...) and then add=TRUE works and you can control the colours better. Default spplot colours are not good for polygons (white-on-white is never a good idea).

Comment: @Spacedman I've been using `col.regions=gray(...)`.  I guess the point is taken and I'll move to base graphics or ggplot and reserve lattice for when I need exploratory trellised visualizations.  Just means lots more `cut`ting and `legend`ing, which I try to avoid where possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To overplot using the `spplot` function, you can use the `sp.layout` argument. For example, create lists of the appropriate layout items, such as

```
spCounty <- list("sp.polygons", county, col = NA)
spState <- list("sp.polygons", state)
```

Then plot, passing the above list items as a list to the `sp.layout` argument:

```
# spplot(county, zcol = "z", col = NA, sp.layout = list(spCounty, spState))
# actually, you only need to pass the second layout item to sp.layout
spplot(county, zcol = "z", col = NA, sp.layout = spState)
```

The x and y limits might not be correct if the two spatial data.frames don't overlap completely. You can correct this if necessary by extracting the appropriate limits from `bbox(obj)`

For example,

```
theMin <- pmin(bbox(county)[,1], bbox(state)[,1])
theMax <- pmax(bbox(county)[,2], bbox(state)[,2])

spplot(county, zcol = "z", col = NA, sp.layout = spState,
  ylim = c(theMin[2], theMax[2]), xlim = c(theMin[1], theMax[1]))
```

[image]