# Plot Maps with different layers in R

Tags: r, maps, spatial

I am plotting some data for German districts in R using spplot. -That works fine.

To make it easier to understand/read the map or locate places, I would like now to add the borders of the federal states. The maps come from [German Borders](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=ae25571c60d94ce5b7fcbf74e27c00e0)

I use readShapeSpatial to load the data and use then spplot with layer to plot the map. However, I am not sure

```
krs <- readShapeSpatial("VG250_Kreise.shp")
bdl <- readShapeSpatial("VG250_Bundeslaender.shp")

krs@data$n <- cut(rnorm(402, 0, 1), breaks=5)
seq.red <- rev(sequential_hcl(n=nlevels(krs@data$n), h=0))
spplot(krs, "n", col=grey(.9), col.regions=seq.red, pretty=TRUE)+
layer(sp.polygons(bdl))
```

I am not sure what part of bdl I need to add to get only the borders.

I would very much appreciate your help!

Thank you!

Comment: Note: don't use `readShapeSpatial`, use the `rgdal` package and the `readOGR` function - this will read in any projection info in the shapefile which is ignored by `readShapeSpatial`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To overplot you can use the `sp.layout` argument, see [this relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873591/overplotting-two-spatialpolygonsdataframes-with-spplot). So in your case you would add the following to your code:

```
bunder<-list("sp.polygons", bdl)
spplot(krs, "n", col=grey(.9), col.regions=seq.red, pretty=TRUE,
       sp.layout=bunder)
```

Which will give you the following choropleth:

[image]